# Does pressure affect pH?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, equilibrium, ph, pressure

Since pH is the function of $\ce{H+}$ ion *concentration*, the change in volume will change the equilibrium according to Le Chatelier's principle and affect the pH. Is it correct, or are there any additional factors?

Comment: [Yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-ionization_of_water#Dependence_on_temperature,_pressure_and_ionic_strength), pH is affected by pressure.

Comment: But the effect is *many* orders weaker then uncertainty of pH prediction or measurement.

Comment: Yes, pressure does affect pH of a solution.
In basic solutions, pH increases with increasing pressure, while in acidic solutions, pH decreases with increasing pressure.

Comment: (It may seem obvious but just in case:) Apart from the effect mentioned by MaxW, the "Yes" answer may be particularly true if your solution is exposed to acidic vapours. For instance if you have CO2 around, more of it will dissolve into your solution with an increasing pressure (see Henry's law) making the solution more acidic.

Comment: @mranvick It would not be pH change based solely due pressure, but because of pressure dependent acid concentration.

Comment: @Poutnik, yes indeed. But since it results in an overall pH modification I thought it could be worth mentioning it. The question being quite laconic, I thought it may be worth mentioning various sources of pH variation with pressure, as they may be encountered in real-life situation by the asker. It was a more generic attempt to emphasize the importance of a pH pressure dependence caused by other chemical phenomena that might be affected by pressure e.g. the dissolution of a gaseous acid (CO2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In basic solutions, the pH value increases with increasing pressure (e.g. NH3 in water) and in acidic solutions it decreases (e.g. SO2 in water). If a reference measurement is made under normal pressure conditions, the measurement result will be correspondingly higher or lower.

Comment: Please could you indicate a source (citation) to support your claim?

Comment: From Albaha University: 
Please look at the following below links which may help you in your analysis:
https://derangedphysiology.com/main/core-topics-intensive-care/arterial-blood-gas-interpretation/Chapter%201.1.4/neutrality-and-influence-temperature-and-pressure-ph
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304420316301943
http://scrippsscholars.ucsd.edu/adickson/content/effects-pressure-ph-tris-buffer-synthetic-seawater-0
http://jes.ecsdl.org/content/112/3/350.abstract
Thanks

Comment: @Krish These links need to be converted into the proper citations and added to the answer. Also, what are "*normal pressure conditions*", exactly?